# Show data from Excel in Datagrid

Tags: c#, excel, wpf, datatable, datagrid

I am a newbie to C # and have the following problem. I am currently writing a program to convert various formats (.xlsx, .xml, .resx). In the first step I would like to have the opened file displayed in a datatable. I think everything should be right, but I can't get any further. Could anyone help me, please? I'm still in despair ... Here's the code:

**Main**

```
       public void MnuOpenClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Open Filedialog
        OpenFileDialog openfile = new()
        {
            //with Filter
            DefaultExt = "*.xlsx",
            Filter = "Excel-Worksheets (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|Ressource-Files (*.resx)|*.resx|Catalog-Files (*.xml)|*.xml",
        };

        bool? browsefile = openfile.ShowDialog();

        if (browsefile == true)
        {
            //Path to Textbox and search for file-ending
            txtFilePath.Text = openfile.FileName;
            string fileName = openfile.FileName;
            FileInfo fileInfo = new(fileName);
            string extn = fileInfo.Extension;

            //Jumps to different classes
            switch (extn)
            {
                case ".xlsx":
                    XlsxReaderAndConverter xlsxReaderAndConverter = new XlsxReaderAndConverter(fileName);
                    xlsxReaderAndConverter.ReadExcel(fileName);
                    break;
                case ".resx":
                    ReadResx(openfile.FileName);
                    break;
                case ".xml":
                    ReadXML();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Class**

```
   class XlsxReaderAndConverter : MainWindow
{
    //public DataGrid dtGrid { get; set; }
    //public ComboBox cmbColumn { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public XlsxReaderAndConverter(string fileName)
    {
        this.FileName = fileName;
    }

    public void ReadExcel(string fileName)
    {
        //Open and create .xlsx-file
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new();
        //Dynamic File Using Uploader....
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet excelSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)excelBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1); ;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range excelRange = excelSheet.UsedRange;

        string strCellData = "";
        double douCellData;
        int rowCnt = 0;
        int colCnt = 0;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        for (colCnt = 1; colCnt <= excelRange.Columns.Count; colCnt++)
        {
            string strColumn = "";
            strColumn = (string)(excelRange.Cells[1, colCnt] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Value2;
            _ = dt.Columns.Add(strColumn, typeof(string));
            cmbColumn.Items.Add(colCnt);
        }

        for (rowCnt = 2; rowCnt <= excelRange.Rows.Count; rowCnt++)
        {
            string strData = "";
            for (colCnt = 1; colCnt <= excelRange.Columns.Count; colCnt++)
            {
                try
                {
                    strCellData = (string)(excelRange.Cells[rowCnt, colCnt] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Value2;
                    strData += strCellData + "|";
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    douCellData = (excelRange.Cells[rowCnt, colCnt] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Value2;
                    strData += douCellData.ToString() + "|";
                }
            }
            strData = strData.Remove(strData.Length - 1, 1);
            _ = dt.Rows.Add(strData.Split('|'));
        }

        dtGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

        excelBook.Close(true, null, null);
        excelApp.Quit();

    }
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: The code does not even run. Visual Studio wants to run the previous working build. And when it was still working on Friday (I don't know why it doesn't work at all today), the file path was displayed in a text box, but the datatable was empty.

Comment: VS wants (warns you) to run previous working build when the actual build resulted in errors. Check ("Error list" window) and repair those errors.

Comment: Thanks, but there are no shown errors in the "Error list"

Comment: Check the "Output" window too. VS may missed the errors in compiler output. If that is the case exit VS, delete the .vs (hidden) folder in your solution root, reopen solution in VS and rebuild it. Anyway you need to find a way to provide us an exact error to get help.

Comment: I found my mistake. I incorrectly declared an object. Now i can report my mistake. the generated datatable does not represent the content of the imported excel table.

Comment: Nice help here on this platform... :(

Comment: Please edit your original question. Add new details what you discovered. Add sample off difference between imported file and the result datatable. Show us what you see.